# What could cause a small shock from an umbrella being held near a lightning strike?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, lightning

I was just outside holding an umbrella when lightning struck very close by. In the instant it struck, I saw and felt a little shock from the shaft of the umbrella into my thumb. It felt quite small.. like a usual static electricity shock from clothing. The handle was plastic but my thumb was about 1cm from the metal shaft. It was raining quite heavily at the time. I am curious about the possible explanation for this little shock. It's hard to find any explanation of secondary discharges online.

Answer (score 1):

One probable explanation I could think of is below.

Your thumb, plastic handle(1cm thick) and the metal shaft together have created a capacitor like structure. Capacitors have this property of letting DC current pass through them only transiently(i.e. very short period of time) after which it just acts as insulator, cutting off the path for the discharge current(lucky you).

It would have been interesting to check the voltage of the metal shaft just after the incident with respect to an earthing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a transformer. The sudden rise/fall in current in the lightning strike generates a strong temporarily rising/falling magnetic field, which induces current in nearby conductors, like the metal shaft. The voltage could have easily been enough to shock you.

That's why standing under a tree in a lightning storm is not good. If lightning strikes the tree, you're a great transformer.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar 10 minutes ago. I was walking my dog with umbrella and a lightning strikes somewhere near. In the same moment I felt a electric discharge in my left thumb, that was touching the metal shaft of the umbrella.

After that, I closed my umbrella and went home.

Never experienced something like that before. I can still feel a light pain in my thumb.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/425687)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely induction: moving charges induce magnetic fields, changing magnetic fields induce currents in nearby conductors: a LOT of moving charge, accelerating, has a greater inductive range; the lightning doesn't even have to strike near you for this to happen. Sept 25, 2023, Fort Myers FL: holding an umbrella in an absolute deluge, heard lightning cloud-to-cloud crackling well above us, and the danged umbrella handle shocked me! Induction... it really works... ow... :-)